# Autonumber and datatable with dbnull exception

Tags: c#, autonumber, system.data.datatable

i was doing some work on a datatable i filled with a oledbdataadapter made from an access database. and i stumbled upon this error:

Turns out that my table has this structure:
ID --> autonumber(PK)

lazos_>text

Asociaciones->text

and when i fill my datatable all values pass to it without any problems with all the correct values. I insert a new row like shown on the "insert row" part.

i do this asumming that my pk will instert the "autonumber" on row creation, but apparently it is not doing it because when i loop trought the rows i get a "invalid cast exception" with a Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."

I COULD insert an id value to the column, but when i update my dt to my database wont it create an error, because i have no way of knowing wich was the last row created?, or do i?

for example lets say in my datatable the last ID is 50, but on the database y previously made a record with id "51" but then erased it, if i inserted 51 based on my dt info, it would give an error right?

```
    //// INSERT ROW
    DataRow newRow = Tabla_Cods_Proy.NewRow();
    newRow["Lazos"] = textBox1.Text ;
    newRow["Asociaciones"] = textBox2.Text;
    Tabla_Cods_Proy.Rows.Add(newRow);
    MessageBox.Show("Enhorabuena!");


//CHECK ID's            
    for (int i = 0; i < Tabla_Cods_Proy.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Tabla_Cods_Proy.Rows[i].RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
        {
            if (Tabla_Cods_Proy.Rows[i]["Lazos_asociados"].ToString() == "")
            {

                listBox7.Items.Add(Tabla_Cods_Proy.Rows[i]["Cod_Cliente"]);
                listBox8.Items.Add(Tabla_Cods_Proy.Rows[i]["Cod_Inelectra"]);
                ID_Cods_Proy_Sin_Asociar.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Tabla_Cods_Proy.Rows[i]["ID"]));

            }
            else
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(Tabla_Cods_Proy.Rows[i]["Cod_Cliente"]);
                listBox4.Items.Add(Tabla_Cods_Proy.Rows[i]["Cod_Inelectra"]);
                ID_Cods_Proy_Asociados.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Tabla_Cods_Proy.Rows[i]["ID"]));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had once similiar problem. What you need to do is that you **retrieve the new identity `@@IDENTITY` of this column once you insert it into table**. You can do that by using `RowUpdated` event.

Here is quick example from [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#Y342) (similiar to your case, see bottom of the page):

```
    public static void Main() 
    {
       //...connecting to access db and getting data to datatable...
       // ...
       // Adding a new row to datatable.
       DataRow newRow = catDS.Tables["Categories"].NewRow();
       newRow["CategoryName"] = "New Category";
       catDS.Tables["Categories"].Rows.Add(newRow);

       // Include an event to fill in the Autonumber value.
       catDA.RowUpdated += new OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler(OnRowUpdated);

    }

    protected static void OnRowUpdated(object sender, OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs args)
    {
       // Include a variable and a command to retrieve the identity value from the Access database.
       int newID = 0;
       OleDbCommand idCMD = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", nwindConn);

       if (args.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
       {
          // Retrieve the identity value and store it in the CategoryID column.
          newID = (int)idCMD.ExecuteScalar();
          args.Row["CategoryID"] = newID;
       }
    }
```